# Load more button only when there's something to load

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I am currently using a script I found on hycus.com to create a load more on click feature on my page. When you click on the load more button, it fetches data from the server and displays it using ajax. It works fine but the problem I have is this: the load more button still shows up even when there's no data to show.

I want the load more button to show only when there's data to show and disappear when there's no data to show.

index page:
jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#loadmorebutton").click(function (){
                $('#loadmorebutton').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "loadmore.php?lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id"),
                    success: function(html){
                        if(html){
                            $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                            $('#loadmorebutton').html('Load More');
                        }else{
                            $('#loadmorebutton').replaceWith('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="postswrapper">
<?php 
    $getlist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 25"); 
    while ($gl = mysql_fetch_array($getlist)) { ?>
         <div class=postitem id="<? echo $gl['id']; ?>"><?php echo $gl['title']; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<button id="loadmorebutton">Load More</button>
</div>
</div>
```

The loadmore.php page has;

```
<?php 
$getlist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id < '".addslashes($_GET['lastid'])."' 
LIMIT 0, 25 LIMIT 10"); 
while ($gl = mysql_fetch_array($getlist)) { ?>
<div><?php echo $gl['title']; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Basically what it this script does is, the index page will load the first 25 items from the database, and when you click on load more, it triggers loadmore.php, which will load 10 more the data starting from the last id loaded already. What I want to do is...to remove the Load more from the screen IF there's less than 25 items in the database and show if there's more than 25 items in the database.

Comment: just a normal <li>item one</li><li>item two</li> kind of structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $getlist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 25"); 
    while ($gl = mysql_fetch_array($getlist)) { ?>
         <div class=postitem id="<? echo $gl['id']; ?>"><?php echo $gl['title']; ?></div>
    <?php } 
    if(mysql_num_rows($getlist) <= 25) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
             $('#loadmorebutton').hide();
        });
    </script>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: hello Sam, your scripts says if rows is more than 25 it should hide the load more button? Shouldn't that be if the row is less than 25 it should hide the loadmorebutton instead?

Comment: hi Sam...thanx for the solution. I changed the greater than sign to less than and it worked. Can you PLEASE post your answer on this page instead [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120743/jquery-hide-show-load-more-button/] and then delete your answers here so that I can delete this page? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your jQuery ready function:

```
if($('#postswrapper li').length == 10) {
    $('#loadmorebutton').show();
}
else {
    $('#loadmorebutton').hide();
}
```