# Jquery hide/show load more button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, show-hide

I have a script, see below:

Index page: jQuery script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#loadmorebutton").click(function (){
                $('#loadmorebutton').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "loadmore.php?lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id"),
                    success: function(html){
                        if(html){
                            $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                            $('#loadmorebutton').html('Load More');
                        }else{
                            $('#loadmorebutton').replaceWith('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="postswrapper">
<?php 
    $getlist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 25"); 
    while ($gl = mysql_fetch_array($getlist)) { ?>
         <div class=postitem id="<? echo $gl['id']; ?>"><?php echo $gl['title']; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<button id="loadmorebutton">Load More</button>
</div>
</div>
```

The loadmore.php page has;

```
<?php 
$getlist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id < '".addslashes($_GET['lastid'])."' 
LIMIT 0, 25 LIMIT 10"); 
while ($gl = mysql_fetch_array($getlist)) { ?>
<div><?php echo $gl['title']; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Basically what it this script does is, the index page will load the first 25 items from the database, and when you click on load more, it triggers **loadmore.php**, which will load 10 more the data starting from the last id loaded already. What I want to do is to remove the "Load more" button from the screen IF there's less than 25 items in the database and show if there's more than 25 items in the database.

Comment: Wrap an if around the html. `<?php if(25 or more){ ?><button id="loadmorebutton">Load More</button><?php } ?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
<?php 
    $getlist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 25"); 
    while ($gl = mysql_fetch_array($getlist)) { ?>
         <div class=postitem id="<? echo $gl['id']; ?>"><?php echo $gl['title']; ?></div>
    <?php } 
    if(mysql_num_rows($getlist) <= 25) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
             $('#loadmorebutton').hide();
        });
    </script>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: nice one Sam! I tried this and it worked...the only downfall was that the hiding was delayed ie. it will show the Load More button for a few seconds before it disappears...so I changed the code and used css instead and it worked beautifully. ie if(mysql_num_rows($getlist) <= 25) { ?><style> #loadmorebutton { display: none; }</style><?php } ?>

Comment: One more prob though...I dun wanna open a new question regarding that! Unlike facebook load more that changes to NO MORE TO LOAD automatically when there's nothing else to show...I have to click on the Load More button one last time before it will check loadmore.php for more items, if nothing then it shows NO MORE TO LOAD...but can this be automated?

Comment: Hi Sam, I just realized that if there is 0 items the script doesn't work! It only works if there's atleast 1 item showing but not more than the specified number. How can I cater for results which is 0?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="postswrapper">
<?php 
    $getlist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 25"); 
    **$cnt = 0;**
    while ($gl = mysql_fetch_array($getlist)) { ?>
         <div class=postitem id="<? echo $gl['id']; ?>"><?php echo $gl['title']; ?></div>
         **$cnt++;**
    <?php } ?>
</div>
**<?php if ($cnt == 24) { ?>
<button id="loadmorebutton">Load More</button>
<?php } ?>**
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

chagne your php script to with coount variable

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
<div id="postswrapper"> 
<?php 
$count=0;
$getlist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 25"); 
while ($gl = mysql_fetch_array($getlist)) {
 $count++;?> 
<div class=postitem id="<? echo $gl['id']; ?>"><?php echo $gl['title']; ?></div> 
<?php } ?> 
</div> 
<button id="loadmorebutton" value="<? echo $count ?>">Load More</button> 
</div> 
</div>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $("#loadmorebutton").click(function (){ 
                $('#loadmorebutton').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />'); 
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: "loadmore.php?lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id"), 
                    success: function(html){ 
                        if(html){ 
                            $("#postswrapper").append(html);                
                            var count = patserInt($('#loadmorebutton').val()); 
                if(count<25){
                        $('#loadmorebutton').html('Load More'); 
                        }else {
                            $('#loadmorebutton').hide();


                        }else{ 
                            $('#loadmorebutton').replaceWith('<center>No more posts to show.</center>'); 
                        } 
                    } 
                }); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: would this still work if I use <h3 value="">Load More</h3> instead of <button value="">???? Cause when I tried it, it didn't work!

Comment: `<h3 value="" id="loadmorebutton">Load More</h3>` might work but remember ids are unique to a page..

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you two options, whichever is more readable to you.

```
<?php if(25 or more){ ?>
  <button id="loadmorebutton">Load More</button>
<?php } ?>

<?php if(25 or more): ?>
  <button id="loadmorebutton">Load More</button>
<?php endif; ?>
```